# Erro ao iniciar o pool de conexões C3P0

Tags: jpa-2.0

configurei o C3P0 e ao iniciar ocorre o erro abaixo.

> WARN  [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool]
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@74a41b98
>   -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more
>   than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last
>   acquisition attempt exception:  java.lang.NullPointerException

Detalhe, o erro ocorre no console do wildfly 10.1 mas a aplicação em si funciona. 
Meu receio é que o pool de conexões de problema mais a frente.

O Meu persistence.xml esta assim

```
<properties>

    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.13:5432/perolaweb" />

    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />

    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />

    <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
    <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true" />
    <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="use_sql_comments" value="true" />
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />

    <!-- C3P0 -->
    <!-- Connection Pooling settings --> 
    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" /> 
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size"    value="3" /> 
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1"/>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/> 
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300" /> 
</properties>
```

Abaixo erro completo

> 08:19:05,156 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH000130: Instantiating explicit
>   connection provider: org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
>   2017-01-16 08:19:05,165 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider] HHH010002: C3P0
>   using driver: null at URL: null 2017-01-16 08:19:05,172 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider] HHH10001001:
>   Connection properties: {useUnicode=true, characterEncoding=UTF-8}
>   2017-01-16 08:19:05,173 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider] HHH10001003:
>   Autocommit mode: false 2017-01-16 08:19:05,173 WARN 
>   [org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider] HHH10001006: No
>   JDBC Driver class was specified by property
>   hibernate.connection.driver_class 2017-01-16 08:19:05,194 INFO 
>   [com.mchange.v2.log.MLog] MLog clients using slf4j logging. 2017-01-16
>   08:19:05,333 INFO  [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry] Initializing
>   c3p0-0.9.5.2 [built 08-December-2015 22:06:04 -0800; debug? true;
>   trace: 10] 2017-01-16 08:19:05,381 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider] HHH10001007: JDBC
>   isolation level:  2017-01-16 08:19:05,406 INFO 
>   [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource] Initializing
>   c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@c6839eba [
>   connectionPoolDataSource ->
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource@f2d2b84b [
>   acquireIncrement -> 1, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay
>   -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0,
>   connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName ->
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester,
>   contextClassLoaderSource -> caller,
>   debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, factoryClassLocation ->
>   null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false,
>   forceSynchronousCheckins -> false, identityToken ->
>   1hgeby99l1a9zqon13hf6ns|535f06ba, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 300,
>   initialPoolSize -> 3, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge
>   -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 300, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 20, maxStatements -> 50, maxStatementsPerConnection ->
>   0, minPoolSize -> 3, nestedDataSource ->
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource@80d91f8f [ description ->
>   null, driverClass -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null,
>   forceUseNamedDriverClass -> false, identityToken ->
>   1hgeby99l1a9zqon13hf6ns|aa3bd50, jdbcUrl -> null, properties ->
>   {useUnicode=true, characterEncoding=UTF-8} ], preferredTestQuery ->
>   null, privilegeSpawnedThreads -> false, propertyCycle -> 0,
>   statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin ->
>   false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout
>   -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false; userOverrides: {} ], dataSourceName -> null, extensions -> {}, factoryClassLocation ->
>   null, identityToken -> 1hgeby99l1a9zqon13hf6ns|2538e5e2,
>   numHelperThreads -> 3 ] 08:19:05,452 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60)
>   HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
>   08:19:05,513 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService
>   Thread Pool -- 60) Envers integration enabled? : true 2017-01-16
>   08:19:35,446 WARN  [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool]
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@74a41b98
>   -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more
>   than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last
>   acquisition attempt exception:  java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.postgresql.Driver.parseURL(Driver.java:532)   at
>   org.postgresql.Driver.acceptsURL(Driver.java:431)     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:299)  at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:285)
>     at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:161)
>     at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:161)
>     at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:147)
>     at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:202)
>     at
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
>     at
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
>     at
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)   at
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
>     at
>   com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)

Comment: Por um momento eu pensei que você tava querendo ligar um robô do Star Wars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri que o problema ocorria porque o C3P0 não estava reconhecendo os paramentros "javax.persistence".

Troquei por parametros equivalentes "hibernate.connection" e não ocorreu mais o erro.

Antes

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://999.999.999.999:5432/aaaaaa" />
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user" />
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="******" />
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
```

Depois

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://999.999.999.999:5432/aaaaaa" />
<property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="user" />
<property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="******" />
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
```